# AngularJS conditional ng-option

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an app angular that can be translate both in french and english. I'm using angular translate to do that. The problem is: I receive an array of object from an API and in those object, I have a property `bookConditionEn` and a property `bookConditionFr` and other like ids.

In a select input , I want to display `bookCondition` depending by the current language.

In the controller, I can get the current language with the `$translate` service

```
            vm.getCurrentLanguage = function() {
                return $translate.use();
            }
```

So, I wonder if in the view I could use a condition in the ng-option.

```
    <select 
      ng-options="bookCondition.BookCondition for bookCondition in bookCtrl.bookConditions"
      ng-model="bookCtrl.bookConditions" 
      name="Condition" class="form-control" 
    ></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditionals to show/hide options by changing the way you are creating the `<select>`:

```
<select ng-options=ng-model="bookCtrl.bookConditions" name="Condition" class="form-control">
    <option 
        ng-repeat="bookCondition.BookCondition for bookCondition in bookCtrl.bookConditions"
        ng-if="vm.getCurrentLanguage==bookCondition.language"
    >
</select>
```

I didn't quite understand how you have your JSON set up so I am assuming you have a property that contains the language (bookCondition.language).  You can compare this against the user's currently-selected language which is returned by your `vm.getCurrentLanguage`.  By the way, I suggest changing that from a function to just be a variable like this:

```
vm.currentLanguage = $translate.use();
```

This should be all you need to do to specify options in a conditional manner.

Answer (score 1):

It worked your way

```
                <select ng-model="bookCtrl.bookCondition" name="Condition" class="form-control">
                    <option ng-if="bookCtrl.getCurrentLanguage() === 'en'" ng-repeat="bookCondition in bookCtrl.bookConditions" value="{{bookCondition}}">{{bookCondition.BookCondition}}</option>
                    <option ng-if="bookCtrl.getCurrentLanguage() === 'fr'" ng-repeat="bookCondition in bookCtrl.bookConditions" value="{{bookCondition}}">{{bookCondition.BookConditionFr}}</option>
                </select>
```